# Linkage error while using Powerclass for test class that uses JAXB

Tags: java, junit, jaxb, powermock, powermockito

```
`java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshal

`Exception(Lorg/xml/sax/SAXException;)Ljavax/xml/bind/UnmarshalException;" the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/UnmarshallerImpl, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type org/xml/sax/SAXException used in the signature
```

I am using Powermock for mocking static class in JUNIT test case. Since my junit uses xml files, I was getting few errors and I have to use powermock ignore like below.

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.xml.*"})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

I get the linkage error along with the below error . Please advise

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory cannot be created
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue resolved after I used all the three imports inside powermockignore

```
@PowerMockIgnore({
        "javax.xml.*",
        "org.xml.*",
        "org.w3c.*"
})
```

Comment: can you please let me which JDK version your using for running the application??

Comment: and is there any JDK version dependency affect on the above statement ??

Comment: @AjayPanchal exactly a year late to the party, but I started getting this error when I tried upgrading the application from JDK 8 to JDK 11. Also side note, configuring the powermock properties file with global-ignore property is more efficient instead of annotating each test class